Bash script that waits until GPU is free
If my PyTorch training script is run twice at once, the second run will fail due to not having enough GPU memory.
So, I want a bash script that I call like ./scripts/wait.sh && ./scripts/train.sh such that training runs only start if, according to nvidia-smi, the GPU isn't being used.
I would like the script to be robust to race conditions where multiple terminals have the wait.sh script running.
Alternatively, it's ok if process state is checked instead of checking nvidia-smi, but I think that might be harder. Maybe Linux has a way to manage lockfiles?
How do I parse the output of nvidia-smi in bash?

Use flock to create a lockfile. The usual way is to run the main program through flock:
flock /tmp/gpu.lock ./roomheater.sh

Use a while or until loop to wait until the GPU is free (if it's currently used by something that hasn't taken the lock).
until <some command to check the gpu is free>; do
    sleep 10
done


https://stackoverflow.com/a/638980/3720510

@Hannu: I'm not sure what that has to do with this topic?

one way to wait for the lock file to disappear, i.e. <some command to check the gpu is free>

flock already does so, in a more reliable way, and it doesn't actually check that the GPU is free.

... then you need to clarify how that is to be used for the loop; I for one don't get it rom what you have above :-) - sorry. Or have I missed something obvious in the Q maybe...

The flock command doesn't need to be used for the loop; it exists instead of any loop. But it only guards against other already-flock-ed processes, whereas if there's a need to specifically check GPU load (in case there are some other, non-flock-ed things using it) then one would probably need a until nvidia-smi | grep whatever (or the 'while' equivalent), checking whether it reports the GPU idle or not.

wouldn't then existence of the lock file be telling that the GPU has been set to work? I.e. is busy.

@Hannu : If the process crashed/terminate without removing the file, the file will still exist. Meanwhile, the lock on the file itself is always released by the OS if the process locking it no longer exist.

It would really help if these details about flock were included in the question. It isn't at all clear if you are suggesting two different possible solutions or two steps of a single solution. At least use the script names from the OP so folks can understand that this roomheater.sh thing is actually the OP's train.sh.

Oh, so this answer has two different options in it? That wasn't clear at all. I suggest updating the answer to make that clear.

As far as parsing nvidia-smi goes you could use
ngpu=$(nvidia-smi -L | wc -l);
idx=$(seq 0 $(($ngpu-1)) | tr "\n" , | sed 's/,$//');
frees=$(nvidia-smi pmon -c 1 -i $idx | awk -vn=$ngpu 'BEGIN {for(i=0;i<n; i++) { gfree[i] = 1 } } $3 == "C" {gfree[$1] = 0}  END { for (key in gfree) { if (gfree[key] == 1) { print key } } }')

which gets you the individual free GPU numbers in $frees and  echo $frees | wc -w would get you the free count. If you only have a single GPU you can just use nvidia-smi pmon -c 1 | awk '{print $3}' | grep C to check if any process is using the GPU for compute. I use the above to set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES on shared multi-GPU nodes as to avoid oversubscription.
For additionally guarding against race conditions, combine with the flock solution of grawity.

Nice! But why only check for C? The value of the type column can be any of ""C"  for Compute Process, "G" for Graphics Process, "M"  for  MPS  ("Multi-Process Service") Compute Process, and "C+G" or "M+C" for the process having both Compute and Graphics or MPS Compute and Compute contexts." (from man nvidia-smi). Is there any reason to only count the C type instead of $3 != "-" {gfree[$1] = 0}? Might even be better to just check for a number in the pid column.

On those nodes I know that only CUDA compute is being done without MPS. With G alone you get your Xorg/desktop server in there as well even though it's probably not hogging your GPU. I do agree that the MPS and *+C cases should be covered as well. So if those cases crop up, change the check to
$3 ~ /C/ || $3 ~ /M/.
For the same reason going by pid alone gets you potential false negatives only doing graphics.

This seems like a useful thing for me too.  So I wrote a script that I'd use.
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_NAME="${0##*/}"
USAGE="Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME needed_vram expect_used_vram command [arguments]"
WAIT_VRAM="$1"
EXPECT_VRAM="$2"

function getnvfree() {
  nvstatus="$(nvidia-smi | grep -o "[0-9]\+MiB / *[0-9]\+MiB" | head -1 | tr -d '[MiB ]')"
  IFS='/' read -r -a nvvalues <<< "$nvstatus"
  echo $(( ${nvvalues[1]} - ${nvvalues[0]} ))
}

if [[ "$3" == "" ]] ; then
  echo $USAGE
  exit 1
fi
if (( $WAIT_VRAM <= 0 || $EXPECT_VRAM <= 0 )) ; then
  echo $USAGE
  exit 1
fi

shift
shift

set -m
while true ; do
  exec {lock_fd}>"/var/lock/${SCRIPT_NAME}.lock" || exit 1
  flock -n "$lock_fd" || { echo "ERROR: flock() failed." >&2; exit 1; }
  # ... commands executed under lock ...

  # Wait for the first GPU to have [argument 1] MiB of VRAM free.
  nvfree=$(getnvfree)
  if (( $nvfree > $WAIT_VRAM )) ; then
    # Then launch the program given in arguments 3...
    "$@" &
    # Then wait until it has used at least [argument 2] more VRAM.
    while true ; do
      sleep 1
      nvfreenow=$(getnvfree)
      if (( ( $nvfree - $nvfreenow ) >= $EXPECT_VRAM )) ; then
        flock -u "$lock_fd"
        fg %1
        exit 0
      fi
    done
  fi
  flock -u "$lock_fd"
  sleep 10
done

The usage is to pass the desired free VRAM followed by an amount of VRAM expected to be used once the application launches.  That way the lock file isn't maintained forever; other instances are locked out merely by the VRAM use.  That way if you specify an accurate RAM requirement that's less than half the free VRAM, more than one process could be allowed to launch.  (You may not find that useful, but I think I will.)
Based on your usage, for a command needing 10000 MiB but which starts up using only 5000, your command line might be:
./scripts/wait.sh 10000 5000 ./scripts/train.sh
The function getnvfree is the part that parses nvidia-smi VRAM use for the first GPU, and does the math to find free VRAM.
